# Add New Item to List

Tags: sapui5

I am working with SAPUI5 and I want to add an item dynamically when pressing a button. I have an XML View and an XML Model. The model is being displayed as an List correctly and I have a form to add a new item.

I want to add the form entries to the List. As my model is an XML Model I have tried making another JSONModel but it doesn't work.

#### XML View

```
<Page>
    <Button text="Siguiente" press=".onPress"></Button>
    <List headerText="Productos" items="{/book}">
        <ObjectListItem title="{title}"
            type="Active"
            press=".handlePressItem">
        </ObjectListItem>
    </List>
    <form:SimpleForm id="f1" layout="ResponsiveLayout">
        <!-- here are the form fields -->
        <Button id="Add"
            text="Agregar"
            press=".addItem" >
        </Button>
    </form:SimpleForm>
</Page>
```

#### Controller

```
onInit: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
    oModel.loadData("model/sampleData.xml");
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it using `.setProperty()` method. [Here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel.html#setProperty) is a link to the API.

As an option, you may loop over the fields of the form, read data from them and update the model as follows:

```js
addItem: function(){
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
    oModel.setProperty("/<key1_path>", sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("<relevat_field's_id>").getValue());
    oModel.setProperty("/<key2_path>", sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("<relevat_field's_id>").getValue());
    ...
    oModel.refresh();
}
```